# Flex 4 Skin: Change skin based on parent containers state

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a custom component *ExpandCollapseMenu* that extends *SkinnableContainer*. This component can have state "normal" or "expanded".
Inside this component I have buttons, with different skin based on ExpandCollapseMenu's state.
This works fine when defining the buttons inside ExpandCollapsMenu's skin class:

```
<s:Group id="contentGroup" top="20" left="10" right="10" bottom="10">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <component:ExpandCollapseMenuButton label="Foo" skinClass.expanded="component.ExpandCollapseMenuButtonExpandedSkin" skinClass.normal="component.ExpandCollapseMenuButtonSkin"  />

</s:Group>
```

But I don't want to define the buttons inside ExpandCollapsMenu's skin class, I want to define them where I use ExpandCollapseMenu. Like this:

```
<component:ExpandCollapseMenu skinClass="component.ExpandCollapseMenuSkin">
    <component:ExpandCollapseMenuButton label="Foo"  />
</component:ExpandCollapseMenu>
```

At this level, I can't reference *skinclass.expanded*, but I got it working by using CSS like this:

```
component|ExpandCollapseMenu:expanded component|ExpandCollapseMenuButton {
    skinClass: ClassReference("component.ExpandCollapseMenuButtonExpandedSkin");
}
component|ExpandCollapseMenu:normal component|ExpandCollapseMenuButton { 
    skinClass: ClassReference("component.ExpandCollapseMenuButtonSkin");
}
```

Is this a good way to change skin based on parent containers state? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to do?  Your methods are very non-standard and I think there might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Create a vertical menu panel, with buttons, toggle buttons etc. All menu elements have a narrow and wide state. Mouseover menu panel = show wide version of all buttons, mouseout = show narrow version.

Comment: How is the narrow version different than the wide version?  Also, when changing states, why are you changing skins?! You do know that Flex skins can have states as well right? They're based on the component states (which can be overwritten/modified).  I suggest you read up on skin states and would instead have the children check what's their size to change states between wide and narrow since the parent wouldn't need to 'tell' them.

Comment: I change skin because the buttons themself already has 4 states. It was inspired by http://googolflex.com/?p=352 . Because you can't have multiple states, the alternative is to have all permutations (8 states), which is a hack IMO. The children selects skin based on standard CSS, they're not told by their parents (in that last version at least, you're maybe right in the first version I described). The ExpandCollapseMenu gets it's size based on the children, so I don't see how the children could check their size to decide their state?

Comment: Note also that all buttons show their wide version at the same time, not only the one you're interacting with.

Comment: So, you're saying that changing the skin altogether depending on state is NOT a hack?! You do know that stated are inheritable right?  It's also very easy to see which state to go to by overriding the updateSkinState() function and just checking if it should be wide or not.

Comment: How can the buttons get notified about their parents state?

Comment: They don't. Again, that's not what I said... Please read up on skins and states.

Comment: I've read up and down on skins and states. As far as I can read, using CSS is one of the recommended ways to set skin? Maybe not that usual for long time Flex developers, due to the lack of support for the 'C' in CSS in earlier versions of Flex. There is no size change in the parent when its state is changed, not before its children change size. So it's a chicken or the egg situation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to solve the problem on a ExpandCollapseMenu container level. When ExpandCollapseMenu's state is changed you should iterate over children and set some flag for each of them.

So I suggest to introduce expanded:Boolean flag for ExpandCollapseMenuButton.

The problem occurs if ExpandCollapseMenu can contain other instance's types. In this case we can solve it using the following two ways:

1. Check components in process of iterating if they are ExpandCollapseMenuButton instances (using is operator).
2. Introduce simple Expandable interface like the following:

   ```
   public interface Expandable
   {
      function set expanded(value:Boolean);
   }
   ```

and implement this interface by ExpandCollapseMenuButton. So you can use is operator in iterator body more flexible way without ExpandCollapseMenuButton dependency.

So the last part of puzzle is to implement setter in ExpandCollapseMenuButton class and switch skin:

```
private var expandedDirty:Boolean;
private var _expanded:Boolean;
public function set expanded(value:Boolean)
{
   if (value == _expanded)
      return;
   _expanded = value;
   expandedDirty = true;
   invalidateProperties();
}

override protected function commitProperties():void
{
   super.commitProperties();
   if (expandedDirty)
   {
      if (_expanded)
         setStyle("skinClass", ExpandCollapseMenuButtonExpandedSkin);
      else
         setStyle("skinClass", ExpandCollapseMenuButtonSkin);
      expandedDirty = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Constantiner. Yes, there will be other instances than just ExpandCollapseMenuButtons, like toggle buttons, buttongroups, sliders etc. But as you say, this can be solved in some generic way, e.g. interface.